# How to create Java Tree Structured object

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working on a eclipse rcp project where I need to create a treeviewer out of TreeStructured Java object. Currently I have hardcorded the Java objects to create the structure and that is working fine. I need to create a method which calculates all the Parents and children object and form the tree structure. It should be a recursive method. I wrote a recursive method to generate a
tree structured java object. But it does not work properly.
I dont know where exactly the problem. request you to help on this. Please find the code below.

```
private FileParent getInput() {

        FileParent root = new FileParent("Root");

        FileParent A = new FileParent("A");
        FileParent a1 = new FileParent("A1");
        FileObject a11 = new FileObject("A11");
        a1.addChild(a11);
        FileObject a2 = new FileObject("A2");
        A.addChild(a1);
        A.addChild(a2);


         FileParent b = new FileParent("B"); FileObject b1 = new
         FileObject("B1"); FileObject b2 = new FileObject("B2");
         b.addChild(b1); b.addChild(b2);

        root.addChild(A);
        // root.addChild(b);

        return root;

    }
```

My recursive method which is to traverse through all the Parents and children  objects
 and creates the tree structured object.

```
FileParent root1 = new FileParent("Root");
    public FileParent getChildren(FileParent root) {

            if (!root.hasChildren()) {
                return root;
            }
            if (root != null && root.hasChildren()) {

                FileObject[] children = root.getChildren();// size two

                for (FileObject fileObject : children) { // 2 times

                    // here children will be the folders
                    if (fileObject instanceof FileParent) {
                        FileParent folder = (FileParent) fileObject;
                        // root1.setParent(folder.getParent());
                        // if (root1.getParent() != null) {

                        root1.addChild(folder);
                        // }
                        getChildren((FileParent) folder);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("FileName: " + fileObject.getName());
                        // root1.setParent(fileObject.getParent());
                        // if (root1.getParent() != null) {

                        root1.addChild(fileObject);
                        // }

                    }

                }

            }

            return root1;
        }
```

public class FileObject  {

```
    private String name;
    private FileParent parent;

    public FileObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setParent(FileParent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public FileParent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }


}
```

public class FileParent extends FileObject {
    /**
     * 
     */

```
private List<FileObject> children;

public FileParent(String name) {
    super(name);
    children = new ArrayList<FileObject>();
}

public void addChild(FileObject child) {
    // if (children.contains(child)) {
    children.add(child);
    child.setParent(this);
    // }
}

public void removeChild(FileObject child) {
    children.remove(child);
    child.setParent(null);
}

public FileObject[] getChildren() {
    return (FileObject[]) children.toArray(new FileObject[children.size()]);
}

public boolean hasChildren() {
    return children.size() > 0;
}
```

}

Comment: "it does not work properly". You will need to provide more detail than that. What's doesn't work?

Comment: @Will I have already mentioned that I am working on Eclipse RCP Project. JTree would not be possible.

Comment: There is one method in treeviewer.setInput(Object obj).If I pass getInput() as parameter It will work fine. But if I pass getChildren() which is my recursive method it does not work. I presume it is the problem with my logic.

Answer (score 0):

In Swing there is interface [TreeModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeModel.html) with [default implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeModel.html) Supposed to be used in JTree and generally not written the best way (like no generics), but can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

> There is one method in treeviewer.setInput(Object obj).If I pass getInput() as parameter It will work fine. But if I pass getChildren() which is my recursive method it does not work.

Do you mean you are calling `treeviewer.setInput(foo.getChildren())`? This is definitely wrong. Read this article: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseJFaceTree/article.html.

Basically, you need to 1) implement `ITreeContentProvider` to provide the tree structure; 2) implement `ILabelProvider` to provide text and images; 3) call

```
treeViewer.setContentProvider(yourContentProvider);
treeViewer.setLabelProvider(yourLabelProvider);
treeviewer.setInput(new Object()); // or anything for which your content provider returns correct roots
```

Comment: I implemented by using contentprovider and label provider. NOw I need to call this treeviewer in different view. there I will pass the FileParent to treeviewer.setInput(foo.getChildren())